# Associate or Raise defects on defect databases

Tags: feature-request

I was thinking that if a given question is agreed by the community to be a bug/defect in a technology (e.g. SQL Server, C#, ActiveMQ, Java etc.) then you could provide the plumbing to link us to the defect database for the tag.  I.e a link to the MS Connect website, SQL Server page.

If a defect was then raised, you could make it easy for people who get the same problem to "vote" for the defect to be fixed.  I.e. update that link to the appropriate defect number in the product's database.

It would be a really nice feature for dev's who hit the same bug, and it would be a really nice way to get Stack Overflow exposure on each of the product sites?  I realise though that there is integration to be done here, but I think it definitely fits the being better programmers mandate for SO.

Comment: Is there something here that can't be accomplished by just posting a link (in a comment or as part of an answer) to the defect?

Comment: No there isn't.  But I'm talking about a really nice, integrated button that does the heavy lifting, especially if a user is unfamiliar with the given product's defect notification process.  It would be a nice tweak, thats all.  Imagine an upvote to register your interest in a bugfix for the issue described on ms connect automatically...

Answer (score 6):

It's a neat idea... But there are a few issues:

- If a public bug database allowed folks to submit "votes" without having an account or logging in (which would be necessary if SO was going to submit votes on your behalf when you voted on a corresponding post), votes would quickly become meaningless.
- There are... a lot of bugs databases. Who's important enough to get the SO integration?
- It's extra development effort on the SO side of things for something that really *isn't* part of the site's core set of goals. Indeed, it would sorta give the impression that SO is some sort of public support database for anyone who wants to avoid supporting their own products, which it most certainly is *not!*
- It can already be handled fairly well by simply posting a link to the bug entry somewhere. Folks who care enough to check it out are probably a lot closer to the target audience for a public bugs database anyway.